# Compute the number of comparisons used to sort the by QuickSort, Python

Tags: python, algorithm, quicksort

So I have this code counting the number of comparisons used to sort by QuickSort method under three different ways in choosing the pivot point. Choose the first element in the array; choose the final element in the array; choose the median of the first, middle (n-th element if len(array)=2n), and final element.
The input file  contains all of the integers between 1 and 10,000 (inclusive, with no repeats) in unsorted order.
This code however only outputs the result of the first case correctly, and outputs zero as the result of the later two cases, I have no idea which part caused this please help!
This is the code

```
from pathlib import Path
file_path = Path("c:/Users/M/Desktop/Al/")
inFile = open(file_path / "QuickSort.txt", 'r')
with inFile as f:
    lines = [x.split() for x in f]  # a list of lists
    f.close()

    tempList =  zip(*lines)           # a list of tuples := transposed lines
    tempList = list(tempList)
    tempList = tempList[0]      # a list of strings
    
    A = map(int,tempList)               # a list of integers
    


def choosePivot(alist,first,last,pivotID):
    if pivotID == 'first':
        pass
    
    if pivotID == 'last':
        (alist[first], alist[last]) = (alist[last], alist[first])
        
    elif pivotID == 'middle':
        mid = (last-first)//2 + first
        listTemp = [alist[first], alist[last], alist[mid]]
        listTemp.sort()
        if listTemp[1] == alist[first]:
            pivotIndex = first
        elif listTemp[1] == alist[last]:
            pivotIndex = last
        else:
            pivotIndex = mid
        (alist[first], alist[pivotIndex]) = (alist[pivotIndex], alist[first])
        
        
    
def partition(alist, first, last):
    pivotVal = alist[first] # initialise pivot as the first element
    leftmark = first+1
    for rightmark in range(first+1,last+1):
        if alist[rightmark] < pivotVal:
            (alist[leftmark],alist[rightmark]) = (alist[rightmark],alist[leftmark])
            leftmark = leftmark + 1
    (alist[leftmark-1],alist[first]) = (alist[first],alist[leftmark-1])

    return leftmark-1       # partition point := where pivot finally occupies
    
    
    
def quickSort(alist,first,last,pivotID):
    numComp = last -first
    if last <= first:
        return (alist, 0)
    else:
        choosePivot(alist,first,last,pivotID)
        splitpoint = partition(alist,first,last)
        (Lsorted,numCompL) = quickSort(alist, first, splitpoint-1, pivotID)
        (Rsorted,numCompR) = quickSort(alist, splitpoint+1, last, pivotID)
        numComp =  numComp + numCompL + numCompR
    return (alist, numComp)
    

def main(fileName):
    pivotList =  ['first', 'middle', 'last']
    
    for pivotID in pivotList:
        A = list(fileName)
        (A, n) = quickSort(A,0,len(A)-1,pivotID)
        print ("number of comparisons: %d", n)


    
if __name__ == '__main__':
        # unit test
#        main('test.txt')
        main(A)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `(A, n) = quickSort(A,0,len(A)-1,pivotID)` sorts the list. The first algo returns correct results, subsequent ones return `0` because the list is already sorted by now.
To avoid this, create a copy of the main list using `copy = A[:]` and then pass a new copy in each iteration. Something like

```py
def main(fileName):
    pivotList =  ['first', 'middle', 'last']
    mainList = list(filename)
    for pivotID in pivotList:
        A = mainList[:]
        (A, n) = quickSort(A,0,len(A)-1,pivotID)
        print ("number of comparisons: %d", n)
```

Comment: I added this line by the end of the for loop “for pivotID in pivotList: ” but still outputs zero. Is this the right place to add this line?

Comment: Thank you so much!!